Customize Message
I am developing a Plugin. I would like to Customize Message. When I delete any post I am getting message 1 post moved to the Trash. and when I delete a post from trash I am getting message 1 post permanently deleted.. I am getting message No posts found in Trash. at the table of list.
How can I customize those messages ?
I would like to customize like below.
1 post moved to the Trash. --->  1 Game moved to the Trash.
1 post permanently deleted. ---> 1 Game permanently deleted.
No posts found in Trash. ---> No Games found in Trash.

you can customise that with the filter bulk_post_updated_messages.

It might make sense to create a custom post type called Game. That way Games will have their own appropriate messages, while other content like Posts and Pages can say the Post or Page has been moved to the trash, etc.

Those messages are specified in the labels argument to register_post_type(), there's a full list of them here.
